# How to show tabular data in a Java web app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, datagrid

Is there any counterpart to ASP.NET's DataGrid (or DataView) in the various J2EE web application technologies (specifically Struts)?
In other words, what is the de facto method for showing tabular data in a J2EE web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach would be to generate the HTML table yourself, and populate within a JSP (e.g. see [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSP/FillingaTable.htm), although I would separate the logic/database code into a servlet rather than code directly into the JSP).

If you're using Struts, then [Struts Layout](http://struts.improve-technologies.com/index.html) may be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

## Vaadin Grid

[Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/) makes a component-based web framework for Java that provides, among many other things, a data grid component with lazy-loading, smooth scrolling, efficient handling of big data, and flexible configuration.

The client-side implementation of *Vaadin Grid* is based on a standalone [Web Component implementation](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid). With the [*Vaadin Flow*](https://vaadin.com/flow) framework, [you can use Grid in Java code](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/components/tutorial-flow-grid.html) without writing a line of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery DataTable](http://datatables.net/) is a good option for displaying tabular data in Java Web applications. This plugin enhances HTML table with features such as pagination,sorting, searching etc.

You can find a good example for the same [here](http://www.programming-free.com/2013/02/gridview-in-java-using-jquery-datatable.html).